# Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Timeout Error (IOAF code 2)

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS application which uses `VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest` to find faces from the camera feed. This is a project I began in 2017 and recently began working on again. I am running the request within an asynchronous `DispatchQueue` but I am  getting the following error:

```
Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Timeout Error (IOAF code 2) 
Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors) (IOAF code 4)
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I get this error in case I use texture that is not properly initialised. Add some basic setup and create texture in swift for Metal like this:

```
    let texDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat.rgba8Unorm, width: 128, height: 128, mipmapped: false)
    textureImage = device.makeTexture(descriptor: texDescriptor)
```